# UI and model to share and update the same class instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am relatively new to WPF and whenever I was required to create a UI for my projects I did something that worked, but I barely think it was done by the book.

Now I have a project where I have three (main) components:

- UI (`MainWindow`)
- custom class that holds the data (let's call it an `EntriesArray` class)
- engine that gets the data from SQL (`Model`)

The EntriesArray class has some properties, like below:

```
internal class EntriesArray
    {
        public string[] values { get; set; }
        public bool newEntrySql { get; set; }
        public bool newEntryUi { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to search how I should organize this application and found out it might use the rules of MVVM. However, I haven't found what exactly the correlation between these three components should be and how to make both the `Model` and the `UI` read/write to the same instance of the `EntriesArray`. To be more precise, I want to have just one `EntriesArray` instance that should be updated by both the `Model` (whenever there are new entries on the SQL server, it should fetch them and add to the original `EntriesArray` and set both the properties `newEntrySql` and `NewEntryUi` of these new entries to `true`, while setting the `newEntrySql` property of the old entries to `false`) and the `MainWindow` (whenever the user minimizes the window, all the entries that are in the array, should have the `newEntryUi`  property of the `EntriesArray` set to `false`).

How should I be approaching that?

Answer (score 0):

You are *kind of* on the right track, but this approach is a bit off.

The View and Model you have right, but it sounds like there is a bit of confusion with the *View Model*. The View Model holds and manages all the data for your UI to display. It also acts as the go-between for your UI to act on the model (via commands).

Your UI will typically create an instance of the view model, which will then either create an instance of the model, or get an existing instance using a Locator pattern. In an ideal world, the Model has no knowledge of the View Model, and the model just responds to function calls and raises events.

Your View model seems especially off, because all your data is stored in a generic "Values" collection, along with who updates what. You should be updating specific, named variables and object types. Coming from the Model, `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be taking care of updating the UI. Coming the other way, the code performing the update on the View Model data should call into the Model to update your DB at the same time.

Please let me know if you need clarification.

Answer to followup comments:

1. `EntriesArray` as it stands is not a good ViewModel, but it is a start. It is certainly *attempting* to fill that role in your current system. I would not have the Model create it. In general, in MVVM, Views know about View Models, View Models know about Models. No other knowledge exists.
2. No, the framework subscribes to the event for you when you create bindings in the View. I personally use and like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation.
3. To trigger a "New entry" style event, you use an `ObservableCollection<T>` for your collection, and bind an `ItemsSource` property to it. That collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and the framework will update the `ListBox` or whatever control you have bound to the `ObservableCollection<T>` for you.
4. If you have a `Entry` class, with a "New" property that is set to true on creation (and use that property to make it bold), that is fine. Duplicate checking should be done as part of data validation, I don't see where a flag gets you anything.

In general, you need to remember that in MVVM, everything on the view is driven by some **data** in the view model. You are looking to model your programming "world" in objects that you can then bind controls to for display.

Comment: #1 Currently my Model initializes an instance of the EntriesArray. Should it be other way around? Can my EntriesArray be called a ViewModel then?
#2 I checked MSDN on the INotifyPropertyChanged, but I do not see how one uses it. Do I subscribe to the event somehow?
#3 If I use the INotifyPropertyChanged, will it be able to trigger an event when there is a new entry, not only when it changes?

Comment: #4 I introduced the newEntry properties to be able to do the following: make the shown entries in bold if the newEntryUi is true; check if duplicates exist between existing entries (newEntrySql false) and new entries (newEntrySql true). Should it be done differently?

Comment: @śmiglidigli See update, and let me know if you are still confused.

Comment: Bradley, the model in MVVM is meant to be a dumb DTO. It does not respond to function calls or raised events.

Comment: Thanks. Seems it's more complicated than I thought. I guess I need to look for some (at least basic) MVVM tutorial, and this time still do it the DIY way, because it needs to be done fast:)

Comment: @CBauer That depends on how you define it I suppose. I have done applications where the Model is a WCF service (which certainly raises events) or a Database (which would certainly respond to function calls). Obviously its an opinion thing, but I don't restrict the concept of "Model" to my DTOs

Comment: @śmiglidigli You seem close, but yes, you should learn basic MVVM on a simple project. Whether you redesign or finish is dependent on time, as you have noted.